# Problem using oracle-serverjre:8 in dockerfile

Tags: java, oracle, docker

I'm trying to create our own docker image from the oracle serverjre:8 image but I'm struggling to get past the first line of my dockerfile:

> FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8

```
Step 1/66 : FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8
pull access denied for store/oracle/serverjre, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

> FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8

```
Step 1/66 : FROM container-registry.oracle.com/store/oracle/serverjre:8
pull access denied for container-registry.oracle.com/store/oracle/serverjre, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

> FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8

```
Step 1/66 : FROM container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre:8
pull access denied for container-registry.oracle.com/java/serverjre, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

> FROM registry.hub.docker.com/_/serverjre:8

```
Step 1/66 : FROM registry.hub.docker.com/_/serverjre:8
invalid reference format
```

Whatever I try, it fails on this first line.

PS: I would like to specify that I connected to the oracle registry before testing with the command "docker login container-registry.oracle.com" and my valid identifiers

Who could help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type docker login then enter your credentials. No need to specify `container-registry.oracle.com`.